# remove last separator from div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following HTML

```
<p><span class="dc2-order-detail-tob siebui-input-align-left">
<span class="oi-label-tob">
    <span id="DC2_Purchaser_Label">Purchaser</span>:&nbsp;
</span> 
<span id="s_7_1_1_0" tabindex="0" aria-readonly="false">&nbsp;<label id="s_7_1_1_0_Label">User esales</label></span>
  <span class="sep">|</span>
 </span>

<span class="dc2-order-detail-tob siebui-input-align-left">
      <span class="oi-label-tob">
    <span id="Status_Label">Status</span>:&nbsp;</span>
      <span id="s_7_1_9_0" tabindex="0" aria-readonly="false">&nbsp;
        <label id="s_7_1_9_0_Label">Open</label>
    </span>
      <span class="sep">|</span>
</span>
```

More data is present in actuall form but I am avoiding it for clarity sake

I need to solve two problems

**1. jQuery selector to remove the extra sep tag that comes after last label.**

As the form is generated dynamically therefore we get a seperator even after last label we need to remove this with dynamically using jQuery but I am not able to get the desired selector to do this. I have tried following selectors but they remove all seperators

```
$('.sep:last-child').remove();
$('span.dc2-order-detail-tob .sep:last-child').remove();
```

**2. Break last div "dc2-order-detail-tob" into next line if complete div cannot come in same line**

Page has several divs that are generated dynamically and sometime the last div values cannot come in same line in that case text wraps and looks something like

```
 Purchaser: Admin   |   Status: Open   |    Start-Dat
 e: 2014-02-09
```

I need that the in that case whole div should move to next line and should appear as

```
Purchaser: Admin   |   Status: Open   |    
Start-Date: 2014-02-09
```

I have tried css **word-wrap** and **word-break** properties but nothing works.
Is there any way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: `$('span.dc2-order-detail-tob .sep').remove();` simple

Comment: This would remove all the separators. I only want to remove the last one

Answer (score 2):

use **`.last()`** in jquery

```
$(".sep").last().remove();
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/kH7mt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to part 1.):

try the following selector:

```
$(".dc2-order-detail-tob:last-child .sep:last-child").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
$(".sep:last").remove();
```